# Sending Image File data in Rest API

Tags: java, spring, image, rest

To a Spring Rest API, I am trying to send a image data in Base 64 encoded String in Request Body - which I will decode and store as an Image file in Server's file System using below method.

```
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String image) {

        BufferedImage image = null;
        byte[] imageByte;
        try {
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(image);
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
            image = ImageIO.read(bis);
            bis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }
```

Encoding Method,

```
public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
        String imageString = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
            byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
            imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageString;
    }
```

However, For a Image file of 100 kb size - The length of Base 64 encoded String is 1 million Characters Approx. This Big size data is not feasible to be sent in rest API request body.

**Is there a better way to send Image data / upload Image to server using Rest Web Services??**

Comment: _"For a Image file of 100 kb size - The length of Base 64 encoded String is 1 million Characters "_ You've done something wrong, the expansion factor is 4/3 (six input bits to 8 bits encoded).  Since you didn't show the encoding code we can't really help.

Comment: 100kb file = 100 * 1024 * 8 bits = 819,200, with the 4/3 expansion factor, it is roughly 1 million.

Comment: Standard way is pass multipart file

Comment: _"100 * 1024 * 8 bits = 819,200"_ the result is ***BITS*** not bytes.

Comment: yes, it is 819200 bits, with a expansion of 4/3, it is 1+ million. I have added the encoding method as well.

Comment: Negative voter, Please add comments.

Comment: Could you use compression and then base64 encode that?

Comment: @JimGarrison, Any inputs ?? - I have added the encoding code as well.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, I am handling this using MultiPart File.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadImage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String imageUpload( 
            @RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile file){
         //upload file using byte date from file
    }
```